# Kendo DataSource Filtering "less then" operator

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Equal operator is denoted like "eq". What is the operator for "less then" or "less then or equal to"?

```
{field:"item",operator:"eq",value:item}
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.operator).

Answer (score 1):

So other operators are:
[`operators-number`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/grid/filterable-operators-number);
[`operators-date`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/grid/filterable-operators-date);
[`operators-enums`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/grid/filterable-operators-enums);
[`operators-string`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/grid/filterable-operators-string)

Comment: Helps if you give him links to the proper language he's referring to, i.e. JavaScript, not JSP.

Answer (score 1):

- `lt` = less than
- `lte` = less than or equal to